# Alternative to disproving $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} < 3$ by exhaustion

Tags: solution-verification, alternative-proof

I am faced with the following problem:

> Consider the statement $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} < 3$. How to **disprove** this claim, for some $n$?

I have taken to disproving this by using a simple counter-example, $n=11$:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n=11} \frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{11}\simeq3.0199$

Thus, the statement is proven false.

If instead of $3$ however, the number were slightly larger, the amount of manual summing I'd have to do would rise very quickly. My question however is whether or not there's a more efficient and elegant way to do this (possibly by induction)?

Comment: Do you know about the integral test?

Comment: There are several ways to prove that the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: The segment from $1/9$ to $1/16$ adds up to at least $8\cdot 1/16=1/2$. The segment from $1/17$ to $1/32$ adds up to at least $16\cdot 1/32=1/2$. Etc.

Comment: There isn't a coherent problem statement.

Comment: Michal's method is easy enough. The Euler-Mascheoni-constant is based on the convergence of $1+1/2+1/3+\cdots +1/n-\ln(n)$ which immediately implies that the harmonic series must diverge , but that would be an overkill.

Comment: The correct formulation of the claim to be disproven is that the sum is smaller than $3$ for every natural number $n$. This is what Adam means.

Comment: I have updated the post with a more concise problem statement :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that for all $n$,
\begin{align*}
H_{2^{n + 1}} - H_{2^n} & = \frac{1}{2^n + 1} + \frac{1}{2^n + 2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n + 2^n}\\
& \geqslant \frac{1}{2^{n + 1}} + \frac{1}{2^{n + 1}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n + 1}}\\
& = 2^n\frac{1}{2^{n + 1}}\\
& = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
H_{2^n} & = (H_{2^n} - H_{2^{n - 1}}) + (H_{2^{n - 1}} - H_{2^{n - 2}}) + \cdots (H_{2^1} - H_{2^0}) + H_1\\
& \geqslant \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2} + 1\\
& = \frac{n}{2} + 1.
\end{align*}
Finally, if you take $A$ any real number, then if you find an integer $n$ such that $\frac{n}{2} + 1 \geqslant A$, you deduce that $H_{2^n} \geqslant A$. In the case $A = 3$, $n = 2 \cdot (3 - 1) = 4$ works thus $H_{16} \geqslant 3$. You obviously don't obtain an optimal bound, and there are methods to obtain sharper bounds, using asymptotic developments like $H_n = \ln(n) + \gamma + \mathrm{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$.